# How to insert over a million records into a MySQL database?

Tags: mysql, linux, bash

I have a sql file which contains over a million insert statements. The official tool for MySQL administration is not able to open it because of its size. Is it possible to insert records using a BASH script?

I tried this so far but it doesn't work.

```
while read line
do
    mysql -u root --password=root << eof
    use dip;
    $line;
    eof
done < $1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
mysql -u root --password=root <mysqlfile.sql
```

Comment: Nice solution. I just have to add `-D dip` to select the database I wanted.

Comment: @Tomas, right, I haven't read further than `mysql` line and therefore assumed you have everything in invocation, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
while read line
do
    mysql -u root --password=root -c "$line"
done < $1
```

Notes:
If the sql contains double quotes (`"`), yo'll have to escape them
If the SQL statements go over multiple lines, you'll have to figure that out

The advantage of this method is each line gets its own transaction, whereas if you fire the whole file in, it could blow the logs being such a large change set